# VBA Outlook calling Excel Macro and Wait till Macro is Done

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am calling an Excel macro from an Outlook rule script.

The process is:
Get mail, run an Outlook rule which runs an Outlook script, open Excel from that script, run the Excel macro, close Excel.

How can I validate in the Outlook rule script that the Excel macro is done, to save and close the application?

```
 Sub AskMeAlerts()
 Dim appExcel As Excel.Application 
 Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook 
 Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
 appExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm") 
 appExcel.Visible = True 
 appExcel.Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!AskMeFlow" 
 appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
 appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
 appExcel.Quit Set appExcel = Nothing 
 Set wkb = Nothing 
 End Sub
```

Comment: Please show us the relevant parts of your code. (i.e. not the whole thing)

Comment: 'Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook

    Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    appExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm")

    appExcel.Visible = True

    appExcel.Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!AskMeFlow"
    ---- Here I want to wait till the macro is done ----

    appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False
    appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save
    
    appExcel.Quit

    Set appExcel = Nothing
    Set wkb = Nothing
    
End Sub'

Comment: I imagine you can see for yourself that this is completely illegible... Please edit your question, place your code there, and format it properly using the `{}` button.

Comment: Thanks for the editing. I didn't see i can actually edit the main question. On the main i know how to present the code...

Comment: OP was "Last seen Feb 21 at 10:50". Just missing these pearls. Others may benefit.  https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Answer (score 4):

You could either

1. Port your Excel macro into Outlook and run it directly
2. Use a *flag* to capture code completion

The code below uses a marker in A1 of the first sheet to catch the code being run (in the Excel portion). I have also tided your code (it was a mix of early and later binding)

*outlook code*

```
 Sub AskMeAlerts()
 Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
 Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
 With appExcel
     .DisplayAlerts = False
     .Workbooks.Open ("C:\TEMP\Ask me question workflow.xlsm")
     .Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!AskMeFlow"
     If .activeworkbook.sheets(1).[a1].Value = "Complete" Then
         MsgBox "Code has run"
         .activeworkbook.sheets(1).[a1].Value = vbNullString
         .activeworkbook.Save
        .DisplayAlerts = True
         .activeworkbook.Close
         appExcel.Quit
        Set appExcel = Nothing
     End If
 End With
End Sub
```

*excel code*

```
Sub AskMeFloW()
'do stuff
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).[a1] = "Complete"
End Sub
```

Comment: I may be reading your code incorrectly, but wouldn't the AskMeAlerts() subroutine simply evaluate `.activeworkbook.sheets(1).[a1].Value = "Complete"` as False and then skip the If block? Should you have a wait function of some sort, either a Do or While?

Comment: @NickPeranzi No. Try testing the code as above (Add a ` MsgBox .activeworkbook.sheets(1).Range("A1").Value` before and after the .Run line).

Comment: So then does the "flag" even matter? Since there is no waiting between the Outlook macro executing the .Run statement and checking the value, does then this mean that the Outlook macro doesn't execute the .Value statement until the .Run statement (the Excel macro) is complete?

Comment: That's correct re sequence. But the OP may have valid concerns that the Excel macro won't complete in the manner desired (which we can't see as we haven't sighted the Excel code). So this is more a validation than an requirement as per the point you make.

Answer (score 2):

A really simple way, is by implementing a lock.

This code is a quick and dirty solution, by checking the existence of a file, in a predefined place.

in `C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm` add this sub:

```
Sub WrapAskMeFlow()
   Dim tmpFile As String
   tmpFile = "C:\AskMeFlow.tmp"
   Open tmpFile for Output as #1
   Close #1
   AskMeFlow
   Kill tmpFile
End Sub
```

In your outlook macro add:

```
 Sub AskMeAlerts()
 Dim appExcel As Excel.Application 
 Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook 
 Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
 appExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm") 
 appExcel.Visible = True 
 appExcel.Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!WrapAskMeFlow" 
 appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
 While Dir("C:\AskMeFlow.tmp")="":DoEvents:Wend
 While Dir("C:\AskMeFlow.tmp")<>"":DoEvents:Wend
 appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
 appExcel.Quit Set appExcel = Nothing 
 Set wkb = Nothing 
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1**

The simplest option in your specific case would be to build the save and quit commands into the Excel macro rather than the Outlook one.

That is, you could amend your Outlook code to:

```
 Sub AskMeAlerts()
 Dim appExcel As Excel.Application 
 Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook 'Is this declaration necessary for some code elsewhere? You do not use this variable and I would recommend removing the declaration.
      Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
      With appExcel 
           .Workbooks.Open ("C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm") 
           .Visible = True 
           .Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!AskMeFlow" 
      'No need to explicitly set alert values or save workbook as Excel macro will handle this.
      End With 
      Set appExcel = Nothing 
      Set wkb = Nothing 'Again, is this necessary?
 End Sub
```

You could then add the following to the end of the "Ask me question workflow.xlsm" file:

```
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
 Application.Quit
```

Note: if you will also be running the macro manually or in other use cases where you do not want the workbook to save, close, and quit, you could consider adding an input variable to the AskMeFlow macro that defaults to False but is set to True by Outlook. I think this is slightly outside the scope of this answer, so I will not elaborate further, but let me know if you are interested in this option.

**Option 2**

Redacted. See Uri's solution; the improvements I suggested do not fundamentally alter that solution.

**Option 3**

Depending on the nature of the Excel code, you could turn it into a function and capture the output variable. Something like the below:

```
Sub AskMeAlerts()
 Dim appExcel As Excel.Application 
 Dim wkb As Excel.Workbook 
 Dim StrOutput as string
 StrOutput = "Excel macro did not complete."
 Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
 appExcel.Workbooks.Open ("C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm") 
 appExcel.Visible = True 
 StrOutput = appExcel.Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!AskMeFlow" 
 MsgBox StrOutput
 appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
 appExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
 appExcel.Quit Set appExcel = Nothing 
 Set wkb = Nothing 
End Sub
```

You would then change AskMeFlow to a function and add the following code:

```
Function AskMeFlow() as String
AskMeFlow = "Uncaught error executing Excel code."
'Your code here
AskMeFlow = "Excel code completed successfully!"
End Function
```

Comment: Option 1 doesn't address the questions (ie detecting when the Excel code is complete). Option 2 appears to, but it is tweaking an existing answer.

Comment: Option 1 suggests, as your option 1 above, that waiting for Excel to close may not be the best recourse in this specific scenario. Your suggestion to port the Excel code into Outlook is functionally equivalent to my suggestion of move all Outlook macro actions that truly depend on the Excel macro completion into the Excel macro. I'm not trying to come off as argumentative, and I apologize if it's coming off that way; thank you for the feedback.

Comment: You are not coming across as argumentative at all - you raised a good question. Likewise my comments on your posts were intended as constructive - even though by other forum standards SO can be quite abrupt and direct. I understand now the logic you intended on Option 1.

Comment: @brettdj - what do you think of my function suggestion (see edited answer)? Appreciate the time to review.

Answer (score 1):

If `Sub AskMeFlow` do calculations without user intervention, I suppose you can just simply track Excel's `CalculationState`.

```
Sub AskMeAlerts()
    With CreateObject("Excel.Application")
        .Workbooks.Open ("C:\Ask me question workflow.xlsm")
        .Visible = True

        ' Ensure Autocalculation is on
        .Calculation = -4105 ' xlCalculationAutomatic

        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .Run "'Ask me question workflow.xlsm'!AskMeFlow"

        ' Wait until calculation is done
        Do Until .CalculationState = 0   ' xlDone
            DoEvents
        Loop

        .ActiveWorkbook.Save
        .ActiveWorkbook.Close
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

It would be even better if the `AskMeFlow` is auto executed in `Workbook_Open` event (within "ThisWorkbook" module).

Answer (score 1):

The Excel macro should finish by closing all workbooks,
and Outlook would wait while there are still workbooks open.

In Excel:

```
// do work
Application.ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
For Each wrkbk In Application.Workbooks
    If wrkbk.Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then wrkbk.Close
Next
ThisWorkbook.Save
ThisWorkbook.Close
```

The Outlook macro can pool until Workbooks.Count = zero

```
While appExcel.Workbooks.Count > 0 :DoEvents:Wend
appExcel.DisplayAlerts = False 
appExcel.Quit 
Set appExcel = Nothing
```

Answer (score -1):

End your code with the following:

```
    On Error Resume Next
    On Error GoTo 0

ExitFunction:
    Set objShell = Nothing

End Function
```